# Negative bosonic spectral functions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

I would like to extend a question asked some time ago.

[Spectral function with negative value](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186969/spectral-function-with-negative-value)

The question is, can a spectral function be negative and if so what does it mean?

The spectral function I want to consider here corresponds to the imaginary part of the retarded or advanced 2-point function. It can be defind (modulo normalisation) by

$$
 A_k(\omega)= (G_k^A(\omega) - G_k^R(\omega))/2
$$

The previous answers to the question cover the zero temperature limit.

I am interested here in equilibrium but at the finite temperature case for bosons and the diagonal elements of the spectral function. So the operators appearing are the hermitian conjugate of each other.

In the Lehman representation we can write the spectral function as

$$
 A_k (\omega) =\frac{1}{Z} \sum_{n,m} |< m| c_{k}^{\dagger} |n> |^2 (e^{-\beta E_n} - e^{-\beta E_m}) \delta( \omega + E_n - E_m)\\
=\frac{1}{Z} (1 - e^{-\beta \omega})\sum_{n,m} |< m| c_{k}^{\dagger} |n> |^2 e^{-\beta E_n} \delta( \omega + E_n - E_m)
$$

So as we can see from this representation the spectral function changes sign at $\omega=0$, so that the occupation number, multiplying the expression by the bose function, is still positive.

Note here that the chemical potential plays a crucial role in defining $\omega=0$.

Phrasing the question now differently: Is there a general argument, which forbids spectral weight below the chemical potential for bosons?

If not is there a special meaning to it?

I am interested here also in the condensate case and the case when the boson number itself might not be conserved. Which might happen if the system is interacting and two different boson species can transform into each other. Then only the sum of the particle numbers is conserved and the chemical potential couples to both particles in the same  way.